# Jenkins with node and pm2

Tags: node.js, jenkins, pm2

I have pm2 installed which also manages the node versions. When I run "node -v" in terminal it works fine. But when I run "node -v" in Jenkins shell script then it says node not found.

Answer (score 0):

If your build machine is a windows machine, you'll need to restart the jenkins agent every time you change your PATH, so that the slave agent/service picks up the change. I am not sure if this would be a problem for build nodes in other OS, but and out of date PATH would explain your symptoms.

To confirm whether an out of date `PATH` is the issue, I would check the contents of the path from terminal, by running `echo $PATH`, and also check where node is installed by running `which node`. The node install location will be in the PATH since terminal can find `node`.

Then I would look at `PATH` as seen from Jenkins, either by running `echo $PATH` on a shell step of a jenkins job or by clicking on the build node in jenkins -> "System Information"-> ctrl+F "path".

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same issue
you need to go to jenkins and add the nodejs plugin and add an installation of it

you go to 
Settings => Global Tool Configuration add a nodejs installation

[image: settings section]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution helped me in another problem where my pm2 process was killed and I couldn't find the solution anywhere and it's simple just put "dontKillMePlease".